# Pyqt5 designer Trying to set a picture as the button background but getting "Invalid Style Sheet"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

from the research I have done in order to set a picture as the button background you: 
right-click the button --> Change styleSheet --> Add Resource --> Edit Resource --> Create a folder and add a prefix and set it to be the picture --> go back once and select the picture and click ok --> and I get Invalid Style Sheet.

[image]

So the question is: What am I doing wrong and how do I do it right?

Comment: Stylesheets need selectors, what you used is just a value that has no meaning without context. Use `background-image: url(:/path/to/image.png);`.

Comment: @musicamante first the link won't help since I want to do it in the designer and not through code. and I tried writing it like you said "background-image: url(:/path/to/image.png);" but the picture still doesn't appear. [link](https://ibb.co/16dcJpM)

Comment: The fact that you use the stylesheet from code or from designer doesn't change anything, the underlying behavior is the same. I just tried with Designer and it works. Are you sure you're using the correct resource path?

Comment: @musicamante I tried again and it worked I have no idea what I did differently, well thanks!